# How to get a graph of all the child components in a React server-side render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My application has lots of different pages (composite components?) which contain the various discrete components that make up the page.  I'd like to be able to run a static function on each of the discrete components, but I only have a reference to the one composite page.

Is there a way I can render the page on the server side and maintain some sort of reference to each component that was included in the page (recursively)?  I'm imagining an analogy similar to the Node.js require graph, which is built when a module is compiled.

I know I can do this at the top level using refs, but this wouldn't work, because I will eventually need refs of refs.

This fiddle is a basic model of what my components look like.  However, in my project I don't even have refs on the top level.

```
var Goodbye = React.createClass({
    statics: {
        serverSideMethod: function() {
            console.log('ya, server');
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div className="goodbye">Goodbye {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});

var Hello = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function(){
        console.log('will mount', this.refs);
    },

    render: function() {

        return (
            <div>
                Hello {this.props.name}
                <Goodbye name="cruel world" ref="g1"/>
                <Goodbye name="cruel world" ref="g2"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World"/>,document.getElementById('container'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/12471/

In reality, I only have a reference to the very top level component through [react-router](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#RouteHandler).  So ideally, I want to be able to recursively call the static on each child node.  However, there are no child nodes, because they are not passed into the render, but rather included by the page.

[Here's some more context of what this looks like in my express router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1583)

[and my related unanswered question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524840/is-it-possible-to-get-the-entire-react-component-graph-from-react-router)

I admit that I might be going about this wrong, so assuming that I have a static that I need to fire on each child component in the page (recursively) any ideas on a better approach?

My ultimate goal is to collect all the private css strings I have defined in the modules and key them up in an object and write them to the head before I render the whole page.  Thanks.